# Is it possible to create a named "fat-arrow" lambda in typescript?

Tags: javascript, lambda, typescript, arrow-functions

Using the traditional function syntax, it's possible to create named functions inline.

```
var fn = function myName(arg) {
    // whatever
};
// fn.name === "myName"
```

Can names be specified in typescript using the lambda syntax?

```
var fn = (arg) => {
    // whatever
};
// fn.name not set
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't look like you can do that, as [the spec](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:arrow_function_syntax) doesn't cover it, only at the end under "deferred" it states "Optional leading Identifier for named arrow function expressions."

Comment: correct. FYI reason for not having it is that it is not supported in ES6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it's a little bit tricky.

The arrow function acquires the name from the variable where it's being assigned. It's called that **name is *inferred* from that variable** (in your case `fn.name === "fn"`). There are some limitations because such name doesn't work as a regular identifier and therefore it can't be used from within the function itself (for the recursion or the events unbinding).

If you use the following code:

```
const joeThrows = (thing: string):never => {
  throw new Error(`Joe took ${thing} and throwed it at you.`);
}

const simonThrows = ({
  simonSays: (what: string):never => {
    throw new Error(`Simon said ${what} and throwed you out.`);
  }
})["simonSays"];


try {
  console.log("== joeThrows fat-arrow %s has name '%s' ==", typeof joeThrows, joeThrows.name);
  joeThrows("hammer");
} catch(ex) { console.log(ex.stack); }

try {
  console.log("=== simonThrows fat-arrow %s has name '%s' ==", typeof simonThrows, simonThrows.name);
  simonThrows("I have a name!");
} catch(ex) { console.log(ex.stack); }
```

Then you will get this output:

```
=== joeThrows fat-arrow function has name 'joeThrows' ==
Joe took hammer and throwed it at you.
Error: Joe took hammer and throwed it at you.
    at joeThrows (/code-demo/named.js:2:11)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/code-demo/named.js:11:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    ...
=== simonThrows fat-arrow function has name 'simonSays' ==
Error: Simon said I have a name! and throwed you out.
    at simonSays (/code-demo/named.js:6:15)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/code-demo/named.js:18:5)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    ...
```

I use the second technique with an object field assign and read expression rarely.

It can be handy when you want to create more functions that will act as callbacks with the same functionality for a different setup and you want to visualize source of exception more precisely then with just a generic name. For example, to dynamically create Redux selectors or FeatherJS hooks that are very generic and can be customized by parameters of the function creator:

```
// Let's suppose we have the types
type HookContext = Record<string, any>;
type ServiceHook = (context: HookContext) => HookContext;

// Then we can define service hook factory function
export const createServiceHook = (purpose: string): ServiceHook => {
    const fn = `serviceHook$${purpose}`;
    return ({
        [fn]: (context: HookContext): HookContext => {
            // Do something here with the context which may throw exception
            return context;
        }
    })[fn];
};

// Later we can create a specific hook function instance that:
// * will have lookoutForSummer.name equal to "serviceHook$summer"
// * will show that name in call-stack in case exception is throw
export const lookoutForSummer = createServiceHook("summer");
```